# SELECT another column than using with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

What is happening when using another column in SELECT than in the GROUP BY statement?

eg

```
SELECT Name from Employee GROUP BY City
```

It seems that the size of the output depends on the unique City elements and if you are having more than one Name per City, it seems that only the first name will be returned.

**What is the meaning behind such a phrase and why is it working?**

I tried the statement `SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers GROUP BY City;`at the [W3S SQL sandbox](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby)

Comment: `It seems that the size of the output depends on the unique City elements and if you are having more than one Name per City, it seems that only the first name will be returned` -- Sounds like you already completely understand it.

Comment: The syntax says that I have to use the same column as I use for GROUP BY for SELECT. So I'm still curious why the code above is working

Comment: Note that W3Schools uses [WebSQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) to demonstrate SQL.  WebSQL might not be totally compliant with the ANSI SQL specification.